# Variable in method can't be assigned to a value

Tags: java, pointers

I want to assign value to the variable "pointer" but it always get a null.
And I open the debugger to watch variable, show that `g.adjList[i].firstedge` is not a null. How this happen?

ps: firstedge belong to the EdgeNode.

```
public static void showAll(Graph g) {
      for (int i = 1;i<= g.numVertexs ; i++) {    
        EdgeNode pointer = g.adjList[i].firstedge;
        while(pointer != null) {
            //....
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try clean-build and run again.

Comment: Try `CTRL+S`. It works wonders.

Comment: it`s still not work...